# avoiding "magic number" for eof C++

Tags: c++, eof, magic-numbers

i have some code that loops while going line by line through a text file to tokenise data and insert it into a vector.

i am using peek() to test if the file is at the end, and if so break the loop:

```
if (fin.peek() == -1)
    break;
```

this works fine, but i am a little bit annoyed about the inclusion of the "magic number" -1.. is there a library for C++ that i can include that functions the same as stdio.h that pre-defines -1 as EOF, or should i just define a const int eof = -1?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return value of ifstream.peek() when it reaches the end of the file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712379/return-value-of-ifstream-peek-when-it-reaches-the-end-of-the-file)

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for `#include <cstdio>`?

Comment: im not asking about the return value of peek(), i know that it is -1 if it is end of file.. i am just asking what is the best way to avoid using the magic number -1.. if there is a standard way to do it in C++, as in C it is predefined as EOF.. id rather not include a c library just for EOF, i can just define it myself as a const int

Comment: [`fin.eof()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/eof)

Comment: [`std::ios::traits_type::eof()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/eof)

Comment: @PeterWood Only useful if you attempt to read a char before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "magic value" -1 is defined as `Traits::eof`, where Traits is the `traits_type` typedef of the type of your **fin** variable.

In other word, `decltype(fin)::traits_type::eof`

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `std::ios::eof()`, something like:

```
if (fin.eof())

    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, loop controls should do the required input; if the input operation fails, the loop terminates:

```
std::string word;
while (std::cin >> word)
    std::cout << word << '\n';
```